# What does "alt" do in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am currently using `ocaml-re` and I saw this line show up in my code. I was wondering what `alt` does in OCaml?

```
let re =
  let open Re in
  alt [rg 'A' 'Z'; rg 'a' 'z']
  |> rep1
  |> group
  |> compile
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is equivalent to "what does `foo` mean in ocaml?". `foo` is just a function name, and so is `alt`, and therefore, aside from naming a function, it has no special meaning in OCaml.

Remember that function application in OCaml are simply a function name followed by its arguments (separated by spaces), with no parentheses. This means that `alt` must be defined somewhere, and that place is in the `Re` module in the `ocaml-re` package. Unfortunately that package does not have documentation online, so you must go to the `.ml`/`.mli` file on github to find the [function](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re/blob/35054f7da04f85ae994b1b66674a8757a4b87b06/lib/core.ml#L824) and its [documentation](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re/blob/35054f7da04f85ae994b1b66674a8757a4b87b06/lib/core.mli#L219).

Answer (score 2):

`alt`  is not a native OCaml function, but a function defined in `Re` (here : https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re/blob/35054f7da04f85ae994b1b66674a8757a4b87b06/lib/core.ml#L824).